# Environment overrides for Linux linker/loader

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, loader

Earlier today I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437279/c-c-environment-initialization) about *environ*, and one of the more [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437279/c-c-environment-initialization#437295) replies suggested that I could gather information using LD_DEBUG.

Now I've known about some linker/loader environment variables (such as *LD_PRELOAD*) for awhile, but this one was new to me. Googling, I found a Linux-specific man page discussing [environment variables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) used by the linker/loader, including LD_DEBUG. So theoretically, I'm set. But in practice, I'm sure I'm missing a whole bundle of tricks relating to this fundamental tool in the toolchain.

Put simply, what else am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite is using `LD_PRELOAD` to work around bugs or misfeatures in GNU libc; for a while `connect` was doing strange things with IPv6 and I just wrote my own version that always, always used IPv4.

Linux users can try

```
man ld.so
```

Also, the `ldd` command, which tells how dynamic libraries are resolved, deserves to be more widely known.

Comment: @matli - there's some thickness on my part. I have used man ld, but it never occurred to me to use 'man ld.so'. Only Googling on LD_DEBUG once I'd heard of it got me into the neighborhood.

@Norman, Re: ldd, yep, I use it all the time.

Comment: Can you post your code? I would like to do something similar where the Oracle installer only listens on v6 if it sees v6 loaded even if there is no v6 configured or even enabled! Its a bug, and we need a workaround. You'd get a big +1 from me :D